# Reference to a button from android system

Tags: android, button

I want to access some of the android already implemented buttons.  Can i get a reference to them? For example, i receive a pairing request. This dialog have two buttons: `cancel` and `accept`.  Can i access one of them and press them?

Comment: Theoretically you can, but why would you want to? If you try to prevent system dialogs from showing than **DON'T**.

Comment: @XaverKapeller i want to automatically accept this pair device..and i don't know how. i even tried to simulate a touch on that button but i didn't succed

Comment: Well you shouldn't do that. You **really** shouldn't. This `Dialog` has to be approved by the user, if your app just comes along and accepts that `Dialog` for you then I would consider that malicious behaviour.

Comment: @XaverKapeller i want to make some automated tests so that's why i need to press this automatically. this app is just for one phone for those tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i access one of them and press them?

No, sorry. That is from a separate application; you have no means of getting a `Button` object that represents them.

> i want to automatically accept this pair device

That should be impossible, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: i want this app only for my phone for some tests. so i don't care too much about security that's the reason why i need to do this

Comment: @Iulian932: If you write your tests using the `uiautomator` tools, your test programs could automate clicking those buttons. But those cannot be run from a regular app on the device.

Comment: thank you! i made it with `uiautomator`. didn't know about this tool